# Sql Query for getting last 8 days data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

For getting last 8 days details I am using this condition in my query.

```
bill_date <= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 8 DAY )
```

But I am not getting the proper result.Last 8 days means 25th april - 2nd may. What is wrong in my condition and is there any another way to do the same?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not getting the proper result"? Can you please share some sample data, the result you're getting and the result you'd like to get?

Comment: What is the data type for `bill_date` ?

Comment: it should be bill_date >=  ( *not <= *)

Comment: Means it is not including every 8 days. And reason I am not proving the result I result contains more than 1lk rows.

Comment: @Abhik type is datetime

Comment: since the dates are stored as `datetime` you may need to have the condition as `bill_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 8 day)` or `date(bill_date) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 8 day)`, the first option is better than the 2nd.

Comment: ... or just `billdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It is work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get last 8 days details

```
bill_date >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 8 DAY ) --After 25th Apr
```

or (if you have records in future date, then use this query)

```
bill_date >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 8 DAY ) AND bill_date <= CURRENT_DATE() -- From 25th Apr - 2nd May
```

it should be `bill_date >=` ( instead of `<=` ), because you want the result after the 25th Apr. So your condition should be `bill_date >=` 25th Apr.

Comment: No. I need information of 8 days which includes 25 and 2

Comment: then you can add  - AND bill_date<=CURRENT_DATE() - also in that script. Query modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
bill_date >=DATE_ADD(CURENT_DATE(),INTERVAL -8 DAY ) AND bill_date<CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 bill_date >= (sysdate - 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bill_date between CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY and curdate() + interval 1 day - interval 1 second
```